# How to configure dxFileUploader to show up like a simple button?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, knockout.js, devexpress, devextreme

I have a dxFileUploader:

```
<div data-bind="dxFileUploader: { buttonText: 'Select file', labelText: 'Drop file here', accept: 'image/*' }"></div>
```

On the UI I got a surrounding white area (div).

How to get rid of it? 
I need only a simple button with an icon and no text that looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: { icon: 'arrowup' }"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following styling for your file uploader

```
.dx-fileuploader, 
.dx-fileuploader * {
    display: inline-block;    
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.dx-fileuploader-input-container {
    display: none;
}
.dx-fileuploader-wrapper, 
.dx-fileuploader-input-wrapper{
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

To set icon to the button do following

```
$("#fileUploader").find(".dx-button").dxButton("option", "icon", "arrowup");
```

If you also need to hide selected files information add one more css rule

```
.dx-fileuploader-files-container {
    display: none;
}
```

See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/uf5vzgdw/

Comment: Can you fix the JsFiddle? It is throwing this error:
"jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).find(...).dxButton is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

Simply just set `[showFileList]="false"`

ex:

```
<dx-file-uploader
  selectButtonText="Select File..."
   [showFileList]="false"
   labelText
   accept="image/*"
   uploadMode="useForm">
 </dx-file-uploader>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hack with fontawesome in

```
onContentReady = e => {
    const node = document.createElement('I');
    node.className = 'cstm-icon fas fa-upload'
    document.querySelector('.uploader-container .dx-button-text').appendChild(node);
}
```

and add some css